# how to pass reference new and old object into stored proc?

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, informix

I have a trigger that looks like below:

```
create trigger theTrig
insert on table_A referencing new as n
for each row(
   execute procedure proc_A();
);
```

May I know how can I pass the new/old reference object into stored proc inside a trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER theTrig
    INSERT ON table_A REFERENCING NEW AS n
    FOR EACH ROW
    (
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc_A(n.col2, n.col3, n.col5, n.col7, n.col11);
    );
```

I usually write 'REFERENCING NEW AS NEW' and/or 'REFERENCING OLD AS OLD' and Informix is quite happy to oblige with the tautologous specification.